# showing the solution linear map is particular solution + solution of homogeneous sytem

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $AX=B$ be a system of linear equations, where $A$ is $m\times n$ matrix and $X$ is $n$-vector, and $B$ is $m$-vector. Assume that there is one solution $X=X_0$. Show that every solution is of the form $X_0 + Y$, where $Y$ is solution of the homogeneous system $AY=O$, and conversely any vector of the form $X_0+Y$ is also a solution.

To show the converse, I just have to check if $X_0+Y$ satisfies the equation which it does. How to show that the solution is of the form $X_0 + Y$?

I am just guessing, $Y$ will be in null space which is perpendicular to subspace space generated by row space of $A$. So $X_0$ is just projection of solution of the system in the subspace generated by row-space of $A$. Still I am not sure how to show this.

Please Help!! Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

Show that if $X$ is a solution, then $X-X_0$ is a solution to the homogeneous system.

Comment: that looks like converse part.

Comment: they are very similar... but not equal: you pass from an equation to the other and conversely.